# Loading interstitial adMob in different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, android

I want to load Interstitial AdMob after 5 second, after the Activity started, in another `Thread`. Is this code right, or I'm duplicating `Runnable`s? Is there a better way?

```
    Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setActivityImmersiveMode();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_normal_mode);


    // loading ads
    handler = new Handler();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadInterstitialAd();
                }
            }, 5000);

        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.setName("AdThread");
    thread.start();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use Thread class you can directly do this:

```
// loading ads
    handler = new Handler();

            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loadInterstitialAd();
                }
            }, 5000);
```

So what is happening your handler will schedule your Runnable after 5 sec, you don't have to instanciate Thread and call runnable again.